# SQL Database not saving changes to table

Tags: c#, sql

I have two nearly identical functions that update two separate columns in the same table of a database. The first takes a value, if changed, from a field on one of my pages and updates the value in my SQL database. The second does the exact same thing, from a separate field on the same page, but the value is not saved to the database. When the page is refreshed, the field returns to its previous (blank) value, while the first can be updated without issue.

Through the use of breakpoints, I have been able to see that the changed value is successfully passed into either function depending on which variable is updated and successfully continued throughout the function until the db.SaveChanges() function. I've stepped into this function to try and see what is happening, but haven't learned much - all I get is: `System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges returned` with a value of 0. My other function returns the value of 1 when it successfully saves to the db.

```
updatedModel.Snapshot = snapshot.snapshot;

db.tableToUpdate.AddOrUpdate(updatedModel)
try
{
   db.SaveChanges();
}
   catch (Exception ex)
{

}
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, snapshot.snapshot);
```

The only difference between the two functions is that the value `snapshot` is replaced with `note`. When I check the function `db.tableToUpdate.AddOrUpdate(updatedModel)` I can see my updated string that I want to save to the db. It is only when I step over to the `db.SaveChanges()` function that my two overarching functions diverge in function.

I have double-checked the existence and accuracy of both columns in my db as well as the existence of them as variables in their respective model.

Comment: Remove the empty `catch` block, and ensure that the observed behavior in debug is not somehow affected by the swallowed exception, and if it still repros, try to boil the scenario down to a minimal repro that you can post as part of your question.

Comment: Yeah exactly. How do you know that an exception isn't being thrown and then just eaten by a catch block that contains no handling code?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft It still reproduces with the `catch` block removed. I'm not sure what else I can post to elaborate on the question though given the information I'm receiving when executing my code step-by-step.

Comment: Is `.Snapshot` a navigation property, or a scalar?  Are you sure that `snapshot.snapshot` has a different key than  `updatedMode.Snapshot`?  And what is `db.Entry(updatedModel).State` directly before `.SaveChanges()`?

Comment: `db.tableToUpdate.AddOrUpdate(updatedModel)` according to the functions comments is: "Adds or updates entities by key when SaveChanges is called. Equivalent to an "upsert" operation from database terminology. This method can useful when seeding data using Migrations."

I've picked up this project from someone else who I have no ability to contact.

What's confusing me is that snapshot doesn't write to the db, but note does in my other function. They both have identical properties (from what I can see), including in the db. Also, .snapshot is scalar.